# Passing large string parameter to external application

Tags: c#, command-line, process, arguments

i'm working on an program which run an another application with multiple (large text) arguments.
When i run this external app via cmd.exe everything works fine (also with multiple lines of flowing text as an argument).

```
ttv.exe -I <root directory> -v vMale -i "large large text" -o test.pcm
```

But when i try to call it from my program i found out that the "large large text"-argument is too large for this call because string limitation of 254 chars?!?

Here this part of code which calls the process:

```
string path = @"<path to exe>";
string arg1= @"-I <root directory>";
string arg2= @"-v vMale";
string arg3= @"-o test.pcm";
string arg4= @"-i """+ text+"";

commandline.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
commandline.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

commandline.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
commandline.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(path, "ttv.exe");
commandline.StartInfo.Arguments = " " + arg1+ " " + arg2+ " " + arg3+ " " + arg4;

commandline.Start();
```

I tried serveral solutions with `commandline.StandardInput.Write()`, `.WriteLine()`, special quote chars like `\"` but nothing works. I think the console auto truncate my string when its too long. Are there any other solutions for this issue? Would be great when somebody can help.
Thank you

Comment: You may need to write the long portion of the argument to an environment variable if the argument length is too short. Environment variable max length is 32,767 characters. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553/

Comment: what value is in your "text" variable?

Comment: What kind of application would take a very large amount of text in command line arguments? Seems very odd. Most applications would just take a file path instead.

Comment: Another option is to use StandardInput for the long text.

Comment: The preferred solution is to write the long text to a file and pass as input argument the file name which contains the long text. CommandLine and environment variables are pretty limitted.

Comment: @fourwhey: do you mean with Set- and GetEnvironmentVariable? I've tryed to store the text in EnvVar and paste it in arguments. no changing.

Comment: @Ichirichi: its a flowing text with white spaces, dots, commas

Comment: @ Dan Wilson: We can say its an translate app. Yeah large text is not perfect for console. But the external app want this large text

Comment: @ Dour High Arch: I'ved tryed that before. With WriteLine() the program dont run when the text is too long
@Alois Kraus: Do you mean write a textfile and only pass the filename to the ext app or the content of the file as an parameter?
thanks for your support

Comment: I do not think your arg4 is being closed properly. Can you please HARDCODE the value for arg4 (do not use + text + varable) and see how it goes?

Comment: Nothing happen when its hardcoded
`var arg4= "-i \"This is a test how many characters are possible in this string. This version is hardcoded and not parted. Only the quotes for this text are special characters\"";` After complete stringlength of 288 chars nothing happens.

Comment: @DennisB: Yes thats exactly what I meant. Many command line applications like compilers do this because the frequently hit the maximum command line length limit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but i got it. Changing the order of arguments brings success:
When i write
 `commandline.StartInfo.Arguments = " " + arg1+ " " + arg2+ " " + arg4+ " " +arg3;`

with

`var arg3 = @"-o test.pcm";
 var arg4= "-i \"long long text\"";`

it works :-/ Could it be that quoted large text shouldn't be as last argument? Makes no sense for me... Thanks for talking about xD

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public void Main(){
        var text = "long text string";

        var arg1= @"-I <root directory>";
        var arg2= @"-v vMale";
        var arg3= @"-o test.pcm";
        var arg4= @"-i """+ text+ "";

        Console.WriteLine( " " + arg1+ " " + arg2+ " " + arg3+ " " + arg4);
    }
}
```

This results with `-I <root directory> -v vMale -o test.pcm -i "long text string`

the last quote is missing

I updated it to this

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public void Main(){
        var text = "long text string";

        var arg1= @"-I <root directory>";
        var arg2= @"-v vMale";
        var arg3= @"-o test.pcm";
        var arg4= "-i \""+ text+ "\""; // changes this line

        Console.WriteLine( " " + arg1+ " " + arg2+ " " + arg3+ " " + arg4);
    }
}
```

I got this result `-I <root directory> -v vMale -o test.pcm -i "long text string"`

try that and let me know

thanks

Update:
The verbatim string literal (@) gets a bit weird with double quotes.  Im not sure if its better to use it or not, but I prefer to not.  escaping characters is necessary both ways so I tend to stick with what I and my team is familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! I've tested your recommendation but already got the same issue. I'm confused about the complete string length (path/filename + arguments) of 286 chars. It doesn't work when i type in one more word... And directly from cmd it works with more than 400 chars?! Don't know where the problem is...

Comment: doesn't sound like a length issue.  I would suspect that something is up with the concatenation.  using the code above what is the result when you type one word in vs multiple words?

Comment: nothing changed when i type in text without whitespaces... it doesn't matter. Is there any other way to call a ext programm with parameters? Fact is that it works fine when i run it outside my program xD